# Swift collections in unit tests

Tags: unit-testing, swift

I am new to swift and I don't understand the implicit type casting, I have this in a unit test:

```
let protocols: AnyObject? = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols"];
```

I need test that `protocols` exists, is an array and contains "foo" and "bar".

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this solution:

```
let protocols: AnyObject? = NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary?["UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols"];
if let p = protocols as? [String] {
    XCTAssertTrue(contains(p, "foo"));
    XCTAssertTrue(contains(p, "bar"));
} else {
    XCTFail("UISupportedExternalAccessoryProtocols must be an array");
}
```

Is there a better way to handle it?

Comment: This is how I'd do it as well. Btw, you probably already know, but you don't need the semicolons.